# "Error occurred during initialization of boot layer" happened when I tried to add a external jar to the project in Eclispe

Tags: java, eclipse, exception, module, jar

I am learning algorithms 4th edition courses, trying to add the textbook library "algs4" to the project, but after I added the file,
it shows `Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Unable to derive module descriptor for /System/Volumes/Data/Users/jason/Desktop/Project/algs4.jar
Caused by: java.lang.module.InvalidModuleDescriptorException: TestAlgs4.class found in top-level directory (unnamed package not allowed in module)`

Answer (score 0):

This happens because [Java 9 introduced modules](https://www.oracle.com/corporate/features/understanding-java-9-modules.html), and the **algs4.jar** has not been updated to support them. You either need to find or make a version of **algs4.jar** that does, or use **Java 8** instead.